# INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody shed some thought on this:

I have a table employee with a column `employeeNumber char(8)` with a check constraint

```
(employeeNumber like '[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]')
```

When trying to insert the following to employee number: '12345678'

I get the following error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "employeeNumber_check". The conflict occurred in database "MetukisDB", table "dbo.TblEmployee", column 'employeeNumber'.

Comment: Just in cqase, give us some specific details: the create constraint SQL statement (or create table where constraint is also created), and the full insert statement. Or equivalent stuff.

Comment: What exact query are you using for the insert?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #T (employeeNumber CHAR(8) CHECK (employeeNumber LIKE '[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]'));INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('12345678')` works fine for me. I presume that the actual value that is being inserted is not what you think. Please provide a runnable sample that fails.

Comment: BTW: Your pattern excludes `0` from all digits. Is that intentional?

Comment: It is intentional, however i still can't get that insert statement to work!

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to check that the INSERT statement is really doing what you think it is? And if you're sending the value from an application, have you debugged it to verify the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work.  However I have two suggestions.

One, get a list of real employee numbers, and use a FK to validate your column.

Two, If this *is* the Employees table, you might want to try.

```
cast( cast( employeeNumber as int ) as char(8) ) = employeeNumber 
AND cast(employeeNumber as int) > 10000000
AND charindex('0', employeeNumber) = 0
```